# Python XMLRPC with concurrent requests

Tags: python, xml-rpc

I'm looking for a way to prevent multiple hosts from issuing simultaneous commands to a Python XMLRPC listener. The listener is responsible for running scripts to perform tasks on that system that would fail if multiple users tried to issue these commands at the same time. Is there a way I can block all incoming requests until the single instance has completed?

Comment: are the clients aware of the conflict matrix? should they be intelligent enough to schedule themselves according to this matrix? how do they activities get synchronized etc...

Comment: are you using SimpleXMLRPCServer as I thought this was single threaded...

Comment: I am using the SimpleXMLRPCServer, but it appears I can launch the same command from different hosts simultaneously, which is what i need to prevent

Comment: So on closer inspection it is executing sequentially, scheduling jobs as a first come first serve basis. With a little control logic SimpleXMLRPCServer should do exactly what I need it to, thanks all!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think python SimpleXMLRPCServer module is what you want. I believe the default behavior of that model is blocking new requests when current request is processing. The default behavior gave me lots of trouble and I changed that behavior by mix in ThreadingMixIn class so that my xmlrpc server could respond multiple requests in the same time.

```
class RPCThreading(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer):
    pass
```

If I understand your question correctly, SimpleXMLRPCServer is the solution. Just use it directly.

Comment: I've been using SimpleXMLRPCServer for a project and am going the other way - requiring concurrent request handling, because when a request is being handled the client call fails with a CannotSendRequest exception. Just a heads up, if you don't want to require implementing retries.

Answer (score 0):

Can you have another communication channel? If yes, then have a "call me back when it is my turn" protocol running between the server and the clients.

In other words, each client would register its intention to issue requests to the server and the said server would "callback" the next-up client when it is ready.

Comment: I'm not necessarily as concerned with calling back clients, moreso in the prevention of conflicting commands being issued by multiple hosts

Comment: can you send back an HTTP 5xx code (server busy or whatever)?

Comment: a lot of subprocess shell commands to copy files, remove files, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are several choices:

1. Use single-process-single-thread server like `SimpleXMLRPCServer` to process requests subsequently.
2. Use `threading.Lock()` in threaded server.
3. You some external locking mechanism (like `lockfile` module or `GET_LOCK()` function in mysql) in multiprocess server.