# Is SimpleXMLRPCServer single threaded?

Tags: python, xml-rpc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python XMLRPC with concurrent requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589150/python-xmlrpc-with-concurrent-requests)

I'm writing a python application which will act as xml-rpc server, using SimpleXMLRPCServer class.

Now my question is: what happens if 2 or more clients send a request at the same time? Are they queued?
Do I have the guarantee that if two clients call the same or different functions they are executed one after another and not at the same time?

Comment: The answer depends on a ton of architectural features.  Please provide more information on what you're doing.  For example, if your server is part of Apache (via mod_wsgi) you have multiple Apache processes each with multiple concurrent wsgi threads, all independent of your application.

Comment: I'm talking about a standalone server with a code similar to this: http://docs.python.org/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html (20.24.1.1). So NOT the CGI implementation (explained in 20.24.2). I'm creating a stand alone server and I even don't have Apache installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the library implementation of `SimpleXMLRPCServer` is indeed single-threaded. You have to add a mixin to make it serve requests in a multi-threaded way:

```
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer

class MyXMLRPCServer(ThreadingMixIn, SimpleXMLRPCServer):
    """..."""
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need your application to process XML-RPC requests (more than one at a time if needed) you may take a look at [Pythomnic](http://www.pythomnic3k.org/) framework.